# How To Make Determinations at Clojure Macro Expansion Time

Tags: clojure

I believe I understand that during macro expansion, a macro does not have access to the things a function has access to, because expansion happens before compile time.

But, I am having trouble understanding is how to perform checks at macro expansion time.

For example:

```
(defn gen-class [cl-nam]
    (fn [cmd & args]
        (condp = cmd
            :name (name cl-nam))))

(defmacro defnclass [cl-nam]
    `(def ~cl-nam (gen-class '~cl-nam)))
```

I would like to check to see that cl-nam is not a sequence. I would like to use count and find out of its length is > 1.

I understand I can unquote the println in the following macro, so that I can get an expansion-time message.

```
(defmacro defnclass_info [cl-nam]
    `(do
        ~(println cl-nam)
        (def ~cl-nam (gen-class '~cl-nam))))
```

But, I am not sure how to go about checking to see what was passed for cl-nam.

I'm reading a lot of Clojure macro descriptions from several books, and am stumped.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A macro is really just a function.

```
(defmacro defnclass-info
  [cl-name]
  (when (seq? cl-name)
    (throw (Exception. "cl-name must not be a sequence")))
  `(def ~cl-name (gen-class '~cl-name)))
```

*Edit:* One could also switch behaviour and recursively call the macro again for the whole list. What you do, depends on your requirements.

```
(defmacro defnclass-info
  [cl-name]
  (if (seq? cl-name)
    `(do ~@(for [cn cl-name] `(defnclass-info ~cn)))
    `(def ~cl-name (gen-class '~cl-name))))
```

The macro expansion is just what the "function" returns. So you have full flexibility on what you do with the macro arguments.

Comment: I am assuming you're using exception handling, to treat the parameter checking as a separate entity from the rest of the macro. In other words, you're making it simpler by avoiding a lot of quoting, unquoting, and re-quoting if it were part of an if form. Your way is cleaner and less messy looking. I just want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: You can also switch behaviour based on the argument. I add an example.